# Using jQuery toggle() in WordPress post to show/hide Tweet button?

Tags: jquery, loop, twitter

What is the appropriate way to use jQuery toggle() function in a WordPress post to show/hide a Twitter "Tweet" button?

The problem I am encountering is when I put the code in my content-post.php, the toggle feature and tweet functionality only work on the first (most recent) post in the stream. How would I go about putting this in the Wordpress loop?

Right now, I am including this code my content-post.php file:

```
<?php if (!is_singular()) { require('post_buttons.php'); }?>
```

The above code includes the Tweet button from another file with this toggle code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#social_trigger').click(function() {
        jQuery('#tweet_button').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the element that is being assigned the "click" event is "#social_trigger", you cannot have more than one of these elements per page. You are searching for an "id" of an element and by definition, you can only have one element of a particular id per page.

You should change your elements to have a class of "social_trigger" and then change the jQuery to find ".social_trigger". You'll likely have to rework your function a bit, but this should get you past the issue of only being able to toggle the first element.

Comment: silly me, I always do that :) This works well now, but I lost my jQuery toggle functionality, rather all of the Tweet butons are visible and no longer hidden. When I click the button with a class of .social_trigger it doesn't do anything. Essentially .social_trigger is toggles the visibility of the button, I hid them on each post for design purposes.

Comment: You are going to have to rework your jQuery here. Since there are multiple instances of "#tweet_button", it won't know which one to toggle on click. You need to use a different method to select that element.

Comment: is this along the lines of what i need to do: jQuery(window).load(function() {
  jQuery('.social_trigger').click(function() {
   jQuery(this).find('.tweetbutton').toggle();
  });

Comment: I figured it out!  jQuery(window).load(function() {
  jQuery('.social_trigger').click(function() {
   jQuery(this).next().toggle();
  });
 });